# Multiple domain redirects for different registration pages for one app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4, I've got several different domain names pointing to same app.

I want root to be able to redirect to registration action with different parameters depending on the url

Below is what I have but it's not working so far.

```
get "/" => "registrations#new", 
      :constraints => { :domain => "domain.com.au" }, 
      :defaults => { :id => '3' }
```

Is there a way to get this working so it automatically goes to registrations controller new action with id of 3 for domain.com.au only?

Comment: could you please provide some examples so that i understand your question?

Comment: @phoet so if I come in as domain1.com.au then I want the redirect to `/users/sign_up/3` and if I come in as domain2.com.au then I want to redirect to `/users/sign_up/5` and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: so are you talking about redirects or routing? i'm not sure i understand your question

Comment: @phoet it's about redirecting from `routes.rb` file